# Google People API - Permanently delete contacts in trash

Tags: google-people-api

I am currently exploring a simple task here :

- What's the best way to automatically empty Google Contact's trash
  where contacts that were deleted via People API's
  **"people.deleteContact"** method are placed at.

At present, Google contact's trash/bin automatically deletes contacts which are placed within after 30 days. However, this duration is not configurable even for a shorter amount of time. Ideally, what I'm looking for here is something similar to Google Drive's **"emptyTrash"** api method, where we are able to permanently empty Google Drive's trash as and when we desire to.

That being said, there exists a way to achieve this and it's more of a RCA approach where I would have to invoke Selenium here. This method is not elegant and I would prefer to avoid it if possible. Thanks in advance for all the suggestions from the community.

Comment: The [trash](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/07/new-trash-feature-in-google-contacts.html) is a rather new feature, so looks like `meptyTrash` has not been implemented into the API yet. You can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) for it.